# d3.js How to pass parameter to php for query condition

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, d3.js

I attempt to combine d3, mysql php [Tutorial](http://www.d3noob.org/2013/02/using-mysql-database-as-source-of-data.html). 
I want to use mysql to store data, and use d3 table to display the result. 
Following the tutorial I successfully connected the sql, and display it.

However, in my example, the `where` condition of sql in `queryData.php` is hard encoded.
As show below: `WHERE pathwayID='1643685' && symbol='VIF'`

I need to pass the parameter '1643685' and 'VIF' from d3 file to php file, how should I do?
And how should I modify queryData.php, thanks.

`d3 file`

```
 d3.json("queryData.php", function(error, jsonData) {
       ....
});
```

`queryData.php`

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
    // load in mysql server configuration (connection string, user/pw, etc)
    include 'mysqlConfig.php';
    // connect to the database
    @mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");
    //Query
    $myquery = "
        SELECT `pathwayID`, `proteinID`, `uniprotID`, `symbol`, `displaySymbol`, `reactomeID`, `cellularLocation` FROM `protein` WHERE pathwayID='1643685' && symbol='VIF'
    ";

    $result = mysql_query($myquery);
    if ( ! $result ) {
        echo mysql_error();
        die;
    }
    $data = array();
    for ($x = 0; $x < mysql_num_rows($result); $x++) {
        $data[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    }
    echo json_encode($data);

    mysql_close();
?>
```

`mysqlConfig.php`

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
    $username="root"; //replace with your mySql username
    $password="";  //replace with your mySql password
    $database="pathway";  //replace with your mySql database name
    $host="localhost";  //replace with the name of the machine your mySql runs on
    $connection=mysql_connect($host,$username,$password);
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I solved this by using ajax to post parameter.

```
$.ajax({
                        url: "./php/querybyPathwayId.php",
                        type: "GET",
                        data: {
                            pathwaydbId: dbId
                        },
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (jsonData) {
                            operation(jsonData);
                        },
                        error: function () {
                        }
                    });
```

and modified the querycentance

```
$pathwayId = $_GET["pathwaydbId"];
$myquery = "
    SELECT `pathwayID`, `proteinID`, `uniprotID`, `symbol`, `displaySymbol`,
     `reactomeID`, `cellularLocation` FROM `protein` WHERE pathwayID='$pathwayId'
";
```